# Чтение записи из таблицы базы данных OleDb

Tags: c++, mysql, база-данных, visual-c++, oledb

Привет. Меня интересует может ли DataSet (или oleDbDataAdapter) вернуть мне значение строки из записи. 
Конкретно, мне нужно сравнить строку из TextBox'а с значением поля текущей записи. Работаю с Visual C++ 2010. Спасибо.

UPD: Смог вытащить строку из ячейки dataGridView

```
dataGridView1->Rows[0]->Cells[0]->Value->ToString()
```

Но мне хотелось бы работать именно с DataSet, а не с Grid'ом